# Delete file if symlink is gone

Tags: bash, symlink, rm, remote

I have tvheadend running on my RPi, and although it stores recordings locally, when the disk gets to 80% full it moves them over to an SSHfs filestore and symlinks to the new location.

I'm looking for a way, in a shell script, to delete the remote files when the local symlink has been deleted (e.g. I delete a recording through Kodi), probably limiting this to .ts files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making several assumptions:

- The remote filename is the same as the local filename/symlink
- The local files are all in a single directory
- The remote files are all in a single directory

You can then list remote files and delete any for which there is no local file or symlink. Something like this could work

```
#!/bin/bash
#
rmt=/path/to/sshfs/storage
lcl=/path/to/local/storage

for itempath in "$rmt"/*.ts
do
    itemfile="${itempath/*\/}"
    if test ! -h "$lcl/$itemfile"
    then
        echo "Removing remote $itemfile with no local symlink" >&2
        rm -f "$itempath"
    fi
done
```

If you just want to delete all local dangling symlinks in a particular directory you can simplify the code somewhat:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
lcl=/path/to/local/storage

for item in "$lcl"/*.ts
do
    if test -h "$item" -a ! -e "$item"
    then
        echo "Removing dangling symlink $item" >&2
        rm -f "$item"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly, however I replaced 'rm -f "$lcl/$itemfile"' with 'rm -f "$rmt/$itemfile"'

Comment: @deejay31 ah yes, my mistake. I'll fix up my code later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, this will do:

```
test -h <symlink> || rm <remote file>
```

The code tests if  exists and is actually a symlink. If not,  will be deleted.